# BindException: Local Error Laravel Adldap2/Adldap2

Tags: laravel, authentication, active-directory, adldap

I am totally new with laravel and more with AD authentication.
I've been following the tutorial of these and I encountered the following problem, which can not find solution when trying to launch the application.

**I have set the `' auto_connect '=> true` and this error appears any attempt to access any direction from my page.**
 If you can also explain to me how these two functions `bind` and `bindAsAdministrator` are based and what items they want to link, can be great:

[BindException: Local Error Browser Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dCgzX.png)

It is worth mentioning that my table has a `username` field.

My `config/adldap.php`:

```
 /*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Connections
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| This array stores the connections that are added to Adldap. You can add
| as many connections as you like.
|
| The key is the name of the connection you wish to use and the value is
| an array of configuration settings.
|
*/

'connections' => [

    'default' => [

        /*
        |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
        | Auto Connect
        |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
        |
        | If auto connect is true, anytime Adldap is instantiated it will automatically
        | connect to your AD server. If this is set to false, you must connect manually
        | using: Adldap::connect().
        |
        */

        'auto_connect' => true,

        /*
        |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
        | Connection
        |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
        |
        | The connection class to use to run operations on.
        |
        | You can also set this option to `null` to use the default connection class.
        |
        | Custom connection classes must implement \Adldap\Contracts\Connections\ConnectionInterface
        |
        */

        'connection' => Adldap\Connections\Ldap::class,

        /*
        |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
        | Schema
        |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
        |
        | The schema class to use for retrieving attributes and generating models.
        |
        | You can also set this option to `null` to use the default schema class.
        |
        | Custom schema classes must implement \Adldap\Contracts\Schemas\SchemaInterface
        |
        */

        'schema' => Adldap\Schemas\ActiveDirectory::class,

        /*
        |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
        | Connection Settings
        |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
        |
        | This connection settings array is directly passed into the Adldap constructor.
        |
        | Feel free to add or remove settings you don't need.
        |
        */

        'connection_settings' => [

            /*
            |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
            | Account Prefix
            |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
            |
            | The account prefix option is the prefix of your user accounts in AD.
            |
            | For example, if you'd prefer your users to use only their username instead
            | of specifying a domain ('ACME\jdoe'), enter your domain name.
            |
            */

            'account_prefix' => '',

            /*
            |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
            | Account Suffix
            |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
            |
            | The account suffix option is the suffix of your user accounts in AD.
            |
            | For example, if your domain DN is DC=corp,DC=acme,DC=org, then your
            | account suffix would be @corp.acme.org. This is then appended to
            | then end of your user accounts on authentication.
            |
            */

            'account_suffix' => '',

            /*
            |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
            | Domain Controllers
            |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
            |
            | The domain controllers option is an array of servers located on your
            | network that serve Active Directory. You can insert as many servers or
            | as little as you'd like depending on your forest (with the
            | minimum of one of course).
            |
            | These can be IP addresses of your server(s), or the host name.
            |
            */

            'domain_controllers' => ['190.168.124.147'],

            /*
            |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
            | Port
            |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
            |
            | The port option is used for authenticating and binding to your AD server.
            |
            */

            'port' => 80,

            /*
            |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
            | Timeout
            |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
            |
            | The timeout option allows you to configure the amount of time in
            | seconds that your application waits until a response
            | is received from your LDAP server.
            |
            */

            'timeout' => 5,

            /*
            |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
            | Base Distinguished Name
            |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
            |
            | The base distinguished name is the base distinguished name you'd like
            | to perform operations on. An example base DN would be DC=corp,DC=acme,DC=org.
            |
            | If one is not defined, then Adldap will try to find it automatically
            | by querying your server. It's recommended to include it to
            | limit queries executed per request.
            |
            */

            'base_dn' => '',

            /*
            |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
            | Administrator Account Suffix
            |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
            |
            | This option allows you to set a different account suffix for your
            | configured administrator account upon binding.
            |
            | If left empty, your `account_suffix` option will be used.
            |
            */

            'admin_account_suffix' => '',

            /*
            |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
            | Administrator Username & Password
            |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
            |
            | When connecting to your AD server, a username and password is required
            | to be able to query and run operations on your server(s). You can
            | use any user account that has these permissions. This account
            | does not need to be a domain administrator unless you
            | require changing and resetting user passwords.
            |
            */

            'admin_username' => env('ADLDAP_ADMIN_USERNAME', 'foo\saaa'),
            'admin_password' => env('ADLDAP_ADMIN_PASSWORD', 'kaa@taa'),

            /*
            |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
            | Follow Referrals
            |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
            |
            | The follow referrals option is a boolean to tell active directory
            | to follow a referral to another server on your network if the
            | server queried knows the information your asking for exists,
            | but does not yet contain a copy of it locally.
            |
            | This option is defaulted to false.
            |
            */

            'follow_referrals' => false,

            /*
            |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
            | SSL & TLS
            |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
            |
            | If you need to be able to change user passwords on your server, then an
            | SSL or TLS connection is required. All other operations are allowed
            | on unsecured protocols. One of these options are definitely recommended
            | if you have the ability to connect to your server securely.
            |
            */

            'use_ssl' => false,
            'use_tls' => false,
```

My `Auth\Guard.php` line with problem:

```
 public function bind($username, $password, $prefix = null, $suffix = null)
{
    // We'll allow binding with a null username and password
    // if their empty. This will allow us to anonymously
    // bind to our servers if needed.
    $username = $username ?: null;
    $password = $password ?: null;

    if ($username) {
        // If the username isn't empty, we'll append the configured
        // account prefix and suffix to bind to the LDAP server.
        $prefix = is_null($prefix) ? $this->configuration->getAccountPrefix() : $prefix;
        $suffix = is_null($suffix) ? $this->configuration->getAccountSuffix() : $suffix;

        $username = $prefix.$username.$suffix;
    }

    // We'll mute any exceptions / warnings here. All we need to know
    // is if binding failed and we'll throw our own exception.
    if (!@$this->connection->bind($username, $password)) {
        throw new BindException($this->connection->getLastError(), $this->connection->errNo());
    }
}
```

My `config\auth.php`:

```
 /*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Authentication Defaults
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| This option controls the default authentication "guard" and password
| reset options for your application. You may change these defaults
| as required, but they're a perfect start for most applications.
|
*/

'defaults' => [
    'guard' => 'web',
    'passwords' => 'users',
],

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Authentication Guards
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Next, you may define every authentication guard for your application.
| Of course, a great default configuration has been defined for you
| here which uses session storage and the Eloquent user provider.
|
| All authentication drivers have a user provider. This defines how the
| users are actually retrieved out of your database or other storage
| mechanisms used by this application to persist your user's data.
|
| Supported: "session", "token"
|
*/

'guards' => [
    'web' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],

    'api' => [
        'driver' => 'token',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],
],

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| User Providers
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| All authentication drivers have a user provider. This defines how the
| users are actually retrieved out of your database or other storage
| mechanisms used by this application to persist your user's data.
|
| If you have multiple user tables or models you may configure multiple
| sources which represent each model / table. These sources may then
| be assigned to any extra authentication guards you have defined.
|
| Supported: "database", "eloquent"
|
*/

'providers' => [
    'users' => [
        'driver' => 'adldap',
        'model' => App\User::class,
    ],

    // 'users' => [
    //     'driver' => 'database',
    //     'table' => 'users',
    // ],
],

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Resetting Passwords
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here you may set the options for resetting passwords including the view
| that is your password reset e-mail. You may also set the name of the
| table that maintains all of the reset tokens for your application.
|
| You may specify multiple password reset configurations if you have more
| than one user table or model in the application and you want to have
| separate password reset settings based on the specific user types.
|
| The expire time is the number of minutes that the reset token should be
| considered valid. This security feature keeps tokens short-lived so
| they have less time to be guessed. You may change this as needed.
|
*/

'passwords' => [
    'users' => [
        'provider' => 'users',
        'email' => 'auth.emails.password',
        'table' => 'password_resets',
        'expire' => 60,
    ],
],
```

My `User.php`:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'password','username'
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];
}
```

My `AuthController.php`:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\User;
use Validator;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\ThrottlesLogins;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers;

use Adldap\Contracts\AdldapInterface;

class AuthController extends Controller
{
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Registration & Login Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This controller handles the registration of new users, as well as the
    | authentication of existing users. By default, this controller uses
    | a simple trait to add these behaviors. Why don't you explore it?
    |
    */

    use AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers, ThrottlesLogins;

    /**
     * Where to redirect users after login / registration.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $redirectTo = '/tickets';

    /**
     * @var Adldap
     */
    protected $adldap;

    /**
     * Create a new authentication controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct(AdldapInterface $adldap)
    {
        $this->middleware($this->guestMiddleware(), ['except' => 'logout']);
        $this->adldap = $adldap;
    }

    /**
     * Get a validator for an incoming registration request.
     *
     * @param  array  $data
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Validator
     */
    protected function validator(array $data)
    {
        return Validator::make($data, [
            'name' => 'required|max:255',
            'email' => 'required|email|max:255|unique:users',
            'password' => 'required|min:6|confirmed',
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Create a new user instance after a valid registration.
     *
     * @param  array  $data
     * @return User
     */
    protected function create(array $data)
    {
        return User::create([
            'name' => $data['name'],
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Handle a login request to the application.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function login(Request $request)
    {
        if ($this->adldap->auth()->attempt($request->email, $request->password, TRUE )) {
            return 'entro';            


            // $this->validateLogin($request);

            // // If the class is using the ThrottlesLogins trait, we can automatically throttle
            // // the login attempts for this application. We'll key this by the username and
            // // the IP address of the client making these requests into this application.
            // $throttles = $this->isUsingThrottlesLoginsTrait();

            // if ($throttles && $lockedOut = $this->hasTooManyLoginAttempts($request)) {
            //     $this->fireLockoutEvent($request);

            //     return $this->sendLockoutResponse($request);
            // }

            // $credentials = $this->getCredentials($request);

            // if (Auth::guard($this->getGuard())->attempt($credentials, $request->has('remember'))) {
            //     return $this->handleUserWasAuthenticated($request, $throttles);
            // }

            // // If the login attempt was unsuccessful we will increment the number of attempts
            // // to login and redirect the user back to the login form. Of course, when this
            // // user surpasses their maximum number of attempts they will get locked out.
            // if ($throttles && ! $lockedOut) {
            //     $this->incrementLoginAttempts($request);
            // }

            // return $this->sendFailedLoginResponse($request);
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First sorry for my english. I found the solution and I'm sure there are colleagues who like me, are new to the world of laravel, Adldap2 / Adldap2 and Active Directory, so I share the answer :).

I start by explaining important message error Adldap2 / Adldap2:

**Can not contact LDAP server:** This occurs when the IP address that we offer to the library, which is supposedly our AD server is not reachable. **It must be emphasized that if we provide any IP that can be accessed, whether or not an AD server, this will no longer display this error.** In short, we can have a completely wrong IP and the library does not indicate this explicitly and / or display the error explained below.

**BindException: Local Error:** It is quite possible that many of you will encounter this error, unlike other errors offered by the library, it lacks explicit description. This error is a consequence of what explained in the previous error. **It happens when we have given to the library, a reachable IP but there is no AD server or configured on it.** In my particular case, my AD server was not set.

Comment: Hi @Skipydie, author of Adldap2 here. The exceptions you've received are exceptions that are thrown by PHP's `ldap` methods. All PHP knows when you try to connect to your LDAP server is either a success or failure. No other information is given. This is the reasoning for no *explicit* reasoning in the exceptions. In fact, in all `BindExceptions` returned by Adldap2, will return the exception message given by the underlying `ldap` exception.

Comment: Hi, @SteveBauman, how can I treat a *ldap_bind* **warning message** when I send invalid credentials through he form? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Hi @NotTheRealHemingway, do you mean a literal PHP warning message or a PHP exception?

Comment: The literal warning message. I was trying to catch it as an exception but it does not work.